# Git cherrypick is not working in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, git-cherry-pick

I want to acheive git cherry-pick via azure devops pipeline from branch A to branch B. My pipeline has a shell step where I am executing cherry-pick command. But when I run the pipeline, it is merging all the contents from branch A to branch B.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the script you run to reproduce the merge behavior you have mentioned? Is it based on the document to [Copy changes to a branch with cherry-pick - Azure Repos | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/cherry-pick?view=azure-devops&tabs=git-command-line) via Git Command Line? Can you please share the script and let us know your expected behavior to use the script?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what functionality are/were you working on that needs to automate a `git cherry-pick` command?